# Anaconda prompt - why there's a syntax error when typing 'conda list'?

Tags: python, anaconda

Why do I get syntax error when I type 'conda list'?

[trying to check anaconda version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deduz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exit the python interactive shell by typing quit() and then run conda list